# Convert an Arc to Polyline

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, g-code

I have 3 points, that will define an arc. 
I would like to convert the Arc to Polyline.

How can I implement this is c#?

Thanks advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find [circle center and radius](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) (if unknown yet), determine start and end (or sweep) angles (with `atan2`) and make series of segments betweeen N+1 points  (where N is number of segments)

```
cx + r * cos(startangle + i / N * sweepangle)
cy + r * sin(startangle + i / N * sweepangle)
```